# [Passportjs][Angular5] No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access

Tags: node.js, angular, passport.js, passport-google-oauth2, passport-github2

I am trying to integrate Nodejs backend api with Angular. I have implemented passpor-google, passport-github, passport-twitter strategy on the backend application.

My backend App url is `http://localhost:3000`
My Frontend App url is `http://localhost:4200`

#### Passport Routes

```
authRouter.get('/github', passport.authenticate('github'));
authRouter.get(
  '/github/callback',
  passport.authenticate('github', {
    failureRedirect: 'http://localhost:4200/login',
  }),
  authController.sendJWTToken
);
```

When i send request from the frontend app it gives me CORS error

#### AuthService.ts

```
githubAuth(): Observable<LoginRsp> {
    return this.httpClient.get<LoginRsp>(
      `${environment.api_url}/auth/github`
    );
  }
```

I have already added CORS on my Nodejs project. How can I resolve this issue please help me

Answer (score 1):

In AuthService.ts just use window.location.href='{environment.api_url}/auth/github'

Answer (score 1):

You can simply write in your html template

```
<a href="http://localhost:3000/login/google">Google</a>
```

and on the backend you just need to have this

```
app.get('/login/google',  passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['profile','email']}) );
```

Comment: This answer worked for me. I had looked for a whole day.

Answer (score 0):

use cors  module [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors)
or else use express cors middleware [express cors](https://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html)

`app.use(cors());` after this any other routes

```
const users = require('./routes/users');
```

or try moving cors middleware to top

Comment: app.use(cors());

Comment: you might be using middleware at wrong scope ie make sure you use it before calling to any routes

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like in the image below [image: this]